# Javascript: question on use of bind in a class

Tags: javascript

It's my understanding the following code requires bind(this,...) because `this.onClick` is bound to this in (*). That’s important, because otherwise this inside it would reference the DOM element (elem), not the Menu object, and this[action] would not be what we need.

Can someone explain this further?  Confused how `this.onClick` really represents `elem.onClick` and why.

```js
class Menu {
  constructor(elem) {
    this._elem = elem;
    elem.onclick = this.onClick.bind(this); // (*)
  }

  save() {
    alert('saving');
  }

  load() {
    alert('loading');
  }

  search() {
    alert('searching');
  }

  onClick(event) {
    let action = event.target.dataset.action;
    if (action) {
      this[action]();
    }
  };
}

new Menu(menu);
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <button data-action="save">Save</button>
  <button data-action="load">Load</button>
  <button data-action="search">Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this.onClick really represents elem.onClick"?

Comment: `this.onClick` is the method on your class. `elem.onclick` is the property on a DOM node that you set to handle "click" events. By binding `this.onClick` to `this` in the constructor, you ensure that the value of `this` when a "click" happens will be the instance of your class (as you yourself explained). Other than that, it's not clear what kind of explanation you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onXXX` event fields are deprecated and should not be used because of the problem with script injection. Instead, use `addEventListener` and use a `ContentSecurityPolicy` (which disables `onXXX` event binding)